# How to convert string to HTML friendly string

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, text

We have `$str = "&nbsp;hello";`

What's the best way to get `$newstr` equal to `&amp;nbsp;hello`; and so on to be sure it is displayed on the page the same way using jQuery?

Comment: Why not just replace the ampersand: `$str = $str.replace(/&/, '&amp;');`?

Comment: The reason is it is not only &, but <> as well. "<div style='display:none;'>not visible text</div>" will show nothing on the page, not this string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to do it with `JQuery` (directly from your JS) you can use `.text()` / `.html()` functions:

```
 $('<div/>').text(value).html();


 $('<div/>').html(value).text();
```

Comment: Untoftunately, I'm not attaching it to div.

Comment: you can pick up the element you want to convert (even <body> for instance)

Answer (score 3):

I think both answers by [Matt Schmiermund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4075011/matt-schmiermund) and [Alex Gidan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2200058/alex-gidan) are directing you to the right place.

You should try something like this :

```
var a = "<div>Your HTML & More</div>";
var span = document.createElement("span");
$(span).text(a)
$(span).html()
```

this will return the following :

```
"&lt;div&gt;Your HTML &amp; More&lt;/div&gt;"
```